# Gatsby.js image source issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I just started learning Gatsby.js with Styled Components and the problem is that the browser doesn't show images. `store.js` is in `pages` folder and images are in `images` folder. Both in `src` folder. The only thing which appears is the value of alt attribute.

```
class Store extends React.Component {
  formatPrice(price) {
    return (price * 0.01).toFixed(2)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Main>
        <StoreContent>
          {products.map(product => {
            return (
              <Product key={product.key}>
                <img
                  width={100}
                  src={`../images/${product.sku}.jpg`}
                  alt="macbook"
                />
                <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                <p>{this.formatPrice(product.price)}</p>
              </Product>
            )
          })}
        </StoreContent>
      </Main>
    )
  }
}

export default Store
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `images` folder into `static/` folder.

Here's what Gatsby documentation [says](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system) about `static/` folder:

> You can create a folder named `static` at the root of your project. Every file you put into that folder will be copied into the `public` folder. E.g. if you add a file named `sun.jpg` to the static folder, it’ll be copied to `public/sun.jpg`

Later reference the images from the web root directory, e.g. `` src={`/images/${product.sku}.jpg`} ``

Comment: well, I did it following these steps so I created static/ folder in src/ folder and set directory "../static/example.jpg" but it still doesn't work

Comment: `You can create a folder named static at the root of your project`: create it in the root directory, not src.